# How should I link to user profile pages in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I heard that it is not a good security practice to allow users to submit forms with user id's. This leads me to believe that its is not good practice to allow the user id to be seen in the url. But I need a way to allow users to see other users profiles.

I was wondering, instead of using

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })
```

If I should use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.username })
```

then in the controller find user by username and return user.

Is this the correct way of going about this?

this is now my link

```
@Html.ActionLink(person.FullName, "Details","User" , new { UserName = person.UserName }, null)
```

this is now my controller action

```
    // GET: /User/Details?UserName=bbob
    public ActionResult Details(string UserName)
    {
        if (UserName == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ApplicationUser aspnetuser = UserManager.FindByName(UserName);

        if (aspnetuser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(aspnetuser);
    }
```

Comment: You are able to get user bu his name insode controller, aren't you?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with sending IDs in a URL or a form POST.  Are you going to obfuscate every single primary key in the database?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087441/using-primary-key-in-asp-net-mvc-urls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer the Username approach, as it eliminates the requirement of having to look up the Id if you already know the username, and it also makes it more difficult for users to "browse" user information by iterating through the list of possible ids.

And also this question is probably going to get flagged. :)